# iPhone, need the dark blue color as a UIColor (used on tables details text) #336699

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to assign blue text like this, exactly like this

[image]

I'm using my own text field.

In hex the color is #336699

I need to access my text color to this, I would have liked to use a UIColor but there doesn't seem to be one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`UIColor` needs it's values in RGB/255.0f. You can find [here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hextorgb.htm) a converter. In your case, your color is R:51, G:102, B:153.

So the code to get your `UIColor` is then:

```
UIColor *myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51.0f/255.0f green:102.0f/255.0f blue:153.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a category for UIColor to convert hex-style colors to UIColors

```
+ (UIColor *)colorWithHex:(UInt32)col {
    unsigned char r, g, b;
    b = col & 0xFF;
    g = (col >> 8) & 0xFF;
    r = (col >> 16) & 0xFF;
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:(double)r/255.0f green:(double)g/255.0f blue:(double)b/255.0f alpha:1];
}

UIColor *newColor = [UIColor colorWithHex:0x336699];
```

Comment: Good one, thanks for posting! Added it to my collection of categories :-).

Comment: BTW, I don't know if you know about the cocoa-helpers project on github (here: http://github.com/enormego/cocoa-helpers). It would be cool if you would submit your UIColor category to them to be included in the project.

Comment: Personally I use this macro: `#define UIColorFromARGB(v) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((v & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((v & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(v & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:((float)((v & 0xFF000000) >> 24))/255.0]` which is used thusly: `UIColorFromARGB(0xaabbccdd)`

Answer (score 2):

I found a blog about this, and in there someone had made a comment where they'd written some code to print out the exact values used to the log. This is the exact specification for the Slate Blue color that Apple uses:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.22f green:0.33f blue:0.53f alpha:1.0f]
```

Here's a category:

```
@interface UIColor (mxcl)
+ (UIColor *)slateBlueColor;
@end
@implementation UIColor (mxcl)
+ (UIColor *)slateBlueColor { return [UIColor colorWithRed:0.22f green:0.33f blue:0.53f alpha:1.0f]; }
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

better use the bicolor converter

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/web-color-to-uicolor-convertor/